# Can I run unittest / pytest with python Optimization on?

Tags: python, optimization, pytest, python-unittest, assert

I just added a few `assert` statements to the constructor of a class.

This has had the immediate effect of making about 10 tests fail.

Rather than fiddle with those tests I'd just like pytest to run the application code (not the test code obviously) with Python's Optimization switched on (`-O` switch, which means the `assert`s are all ignored). But looking at the docs and searching I can't find a way to do this.

I'm slightly wondering whether this might be bad practice, as arguably the time to see whether `assert`s fail may be during testing.

On the other hand, another thought is that you might have certain tests (integration tests, etc.) which *should* be run without optimisation, so that the `assert`s take effect, and other tests where you are being less scrupulous about the objects you are creating, where it might be justifiable to ignore the `assert`s.

`assert`s obviously qualify as "part of testing"... I'd like to add more to some of my constructors and other methods, typically to check parameters, but without making hundreds of tests fail, or have to become much more complicated.

Comment: Why don't you fix the code that failed the assertions? You either found bugs in your code, or the failed assertions are meaningless and should be removed.

Comment: I tried to explain that: that would involve more scrupulousness about the parameters passed. When you pass a Mock as a parameter, you only give it the minimal possible characteristics for it to act as a fake object.

Comment: If it's worth adding the assertion, it's worth configuring your Mock correctly.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I'm not sure I agree: I think `assert`s act as quality checks in their own right: they don't necessarily have to work in cooperation with tests.

Comment: If you are picking and choosing what preconditions can be ignored for a particular test, then your tests are fragile. Just because a function that expects an argument of type `Foo` doesn't use *every* feature of an instance of `Foo` does not mean you should take shortcuts and provide a broken `Foo` to the test.

Comment: See my answer and the comments with Florin C. As you can see in the `Verifier` class, one of these checks checks that the `pathlib.Path` is a real file. But in some tests I pass such an object without creating a file (in a temp directory) because the overhead of doing that serves no purpose whatsoever. But on the other hand, to make the class more able to flag up immediately a rash future code change, it's a good check.

Answer (score -1):

The best way in this case would be to move all assert statements inside your test code. Maybe even switch to https://pytest.org/ as it is already using assert for test evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. I am already using pytest. So you suggest essentially creating a test for each method/constructor where I want to run checks on the parameters, and remove the `assert`s completely from the application code. It's a possibility... but for example, more complex tests, integration tests, etc., wouldn't then have the benefit of the parameter-checking. Nor indeed when the app itself was run with Optimization at "off".

Comment: If those asserts are useful for production code and you would not want them disabled, then a better way would be to turn them into ifs. But keeping them in production code and disabling them through optimisation flag while testing will defeat their purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you can't in fact do this.

Florin and chepner have both made me wonder whether and to what extent this is desirable. But one can imagine various ways of simulating something like this, for example a `Verifier` class:

```
class ProjectFile():
    def __init__(self, project, file_path, project_file_dict=None):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.project_file_dict = project_file_dict
        if __debug__:
            Verifier.check(self, inspect.stack()[0][3]) # gives name of method we're in

class Verifier():
    @staticmethod
    def check(object, method, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'object {object} method {method}')
        if type(object) == ProjectFile:
            project_file = object
            if method == '__init__':
                # run some real-world checks, etc.:
                assert project_file.file_path.is_file()
                assert project_file.file_path.suffix.lower() == '.docx'
                assert isinstance(project_file.file_path, pathlib.Path)
                if project_file.project_file_dict != None:
                    assert isinstance(project_file.project_file_dict, dict)
```

Then you can patch out the `Verifier.check` method easily enough in the testing code:

```
def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
verifier_class.Verifier.check = do_nothing
```

... so you don't even have to clutter your methods up with another fixture or whatever. Obviously you can do this on a module-by-module basis so, as I said, some modules might choose not to do this (integration tests, etc.)

Comment: Even though, this might work it is simply obfuscated coding. The checks you provided here as examples definitely belong to production code. And if you are concerned with "clutter" then moving common validation behavior during initialisation into a base class or a special mixin class is the most expressive choice.

Comment: Mixin is just a base class which adds a very specific feature. If we're considering your checks, maybe it worths to split the checks in a couple of classes: `AcceptsDocx` where you define only the init method which will raise an exception if the some argument is not valid file with `.docx` extension. With this approach you move such checks outside, but still keep the value of running them, and gives you the opportunity to name them and apply where needed.

Comment: By the way, although you say these checks "definitely belong to production code", that might be true if they are in isolation... but actually the code which creates a `ProjectFile` has no way of passing a third parameter which is not a `dict`, or indeed a `pathlib.Path` which is not an existing file (except in certain tests). These `assert`s therefore function as failsafes against rash future code modifications.

Comment: Alright, your original question pointed that you are looking for a best practice. Yet, every real life context might have something particular and now I understand the purpose.